# Python Win32API SetFileAttributes For Removables

Tags: python, winapi

I'm writing an app to set attributes of pen drives. I could set all the files and subfolders with "normal" permissions. But when I try setting the root path (like "k:/"), it doesn't work. How can we set the root of a removable?

Code I use to set permissions on Windows:

```
win32api.SetFileAttributes("k:/", win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

The root path is not a file or a folder, and doesn't have attributes strictly speaking. Are you trying to set the attribtues of all files and folders? If so, you may want to loop through all files and folders in the root directory using os.listdir

Comment: What I want to do is copying a subfolder's contents into root path.

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you able to do the same function from the command prompt? I.e. copy f:\blabla\*.* f:\

Comment: As you said copying files into "f:\" is not available in DOS. Is there a way to do such copying.

Comment: your issue is not a python problem, but something bigger. without more details it's impossible to say but this isnt the right place for it.

Comment: I decided to use SHFileOperation for this process. It's definitely what I look for. It works perfectly.